# Mal manejo de eventos [SFML]

Tags: c++, c++11

Nesesito saber el porque mi programa explota sin razon alguna, y como podria solucionarlo, estoy avanzando en la arquitectura de un juego, muy sencilla, por ahora solo tengo la clase `Stage` que sirve como el evento principal el cual dibujara en la ventana todo lo que le agregue. Trato de usar lo mas que puedo, el patron de diseño iterator.

Este es `Stage.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Stage {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow *window;
    std::vector <sf::Sprite> all_sprites;
public:
    Stage           ();
    Stage           (int width, int height, sf::String name);

    void addObj     (sf::Sprite newobject);
    void removeObj  (sf::Sprite ocurrence);

    void renderize  ();
    void run        ();
};
```

Este es `Stage.cpp`:

```
#include "Stage.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Stage::Stage() { window = nullptr; }

Stage::Stage(int width, int height, sf::String name) {
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(width, height), name);
}

void Stage::addObj(sf::Sprite obj) { all_sprites.push_back(obj); }

void Stage::removeObj(sf::Sprite obj) {
    for (auto it = all_sprites.begin(); it != all_sprites.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).getPosition() == obj.getPosition()) {
            all_sprites.erase(it);
        }
    }
}

void Stage::renderize() {
    window->clear(sf::Color::Blue);
    for (auto it = all_sprites.begin(); it != all_sprites.end(); it++) { window->draw(*it); }
    window->display();
}

void Stage::run() {
    while (window->isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window->pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window->close();
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window->close();
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                    std::cout << "Left click detected!" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        renderize();
    }
}
```

finalmente este es mi `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Stage.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>


int main() {
    Stage app(640, 480, "Game #1");
    sf::Texture text;
    text.loadFromFile("pic/life.png");
    sf::Sprite sprite(text);
    app.addObj(sprite);
    app.run();
    return 0;
}
```

El programa cumple perfectamente con la sintaxis, la logica la veo toda bien  y nisiquiera me sale algun warning. Pero cuando lo corro el programa simplemente se autocierra luego de unos 2 segundos, tambien he notado que al agregar un evento click, se aumenta este tiempo alargando la vida del programa, pero al final ocurre lo mismo. Quiero que se ejecute hasta q yo le de `esc` o darle click al boton cerrar, no se porque mi while infinito tiene fin.

¿que me recomiendan que haga para solucionarlo?

Comment: Me sería de mucha ayuda que describieses con más detalle el "*mi programa explota*". ¿Qué mensajes aparecen en el debugger? ¿En la consola?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster que un programa explota es que se cierra repentinamente sin aviso alguno. No entiendo que sucede lo compilo y no me muestra ningun error, se que algo esta ocurriendo con los eventos que manipula sfml, es por eso que pregunto por un experto que sepa como se ha implementado sfml, no entiendo porque se cierra de la nada, se supone que el while debe correr hasta que yo presione excape o click al boton cerrar y no es asi. Pienso adjuntar un video, quiza sea un bug, como dije esto ocurre solo cuando le pongo un evento en cola.

Comment: lamento mucho no poder proporcionar informacion sobre en tiempo de ejecucion, el problema es que el programa funciona bien y no muestra ningun error. Sucede tal cual menciono, compilo, ejecuta y no hago nada(nisiquiera le paso el mouse en cima) y se autocierra luego de unos segundos.

Comment: @RenatoA. ejecuta el programa en modo compilación desde tu IDE y fuerza el error, debería mostrarte la pila de llamadas e información alrededor del error además de la consola.

Comment: pude arreglar el error, agregando un reloj que sincronizara con los fps. muchas gracias por su interes, no aceptare ninguna respuesta y eliminare la pregunta cuando acabe la recompensa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solucioné el problema agregando un reloj para sincronizar los fps del juego, de esa forma los eventos tienen un tiempo definido por frame:

```
srand(time(NULL));
window->setFramerateLimit(60);
```

Con esto hecho los eventos se manejan adecuadamente ya que los ponemos bajo sincronía del reloj del sistema.

Es todo lo que pude entender luego de leer exhaustivamente la documentación. Sé que no es una buena respuesta pero a lo mejor a alguien le servirá esto.

Comment: Qué bien que compartas tu descubrimiento, a buen seguro alguien en el futuro agradecerá que lo hicieras.